# Configure GNU Screen's colors?

Tags: linux, bash, colors, terminal, gnu-screen

GNU Screen gives my bash prompt nice colors, though the dark blue is hard to read on a black background. I can change the ls colors using /etc/DIR_COLORS but the bash prompt in screen doesn't get affected by this.

Is there any way I can modify the colors used by screen?

Comment: I don't see how this relates to screen - you should get the same colors in an ordinary bash, don't you?

Comment: Certain terminal software has awkward default colors, and that may include a too-dark blue. Consider utilizing the color values from [the CGA set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_8-bit_computer_hardware_palettes#CGA) to get good results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the colors of the prompt from your bashrc. Mine is configured thus:

```
#/usr/bashrc
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\     [\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[1;34m\]\u \[\e[4;33m\]/-\\\[\e[0m\] \ [\e[1;32m\]-> \w\[\e[0m\]: ' 
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

More can be found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt).

Hope this comes in Handy